# R, ggplot; Control size of symbols and line thickness independently in legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot looking principally like this when based on the mpg-dataset:

```
library(datasets)    
plot2 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(
      x = cty, 
      y = hwy,
      group = as.factor(cyl),
      shape = as.factor(cyl),
      linetype = as.factor(cyl)),
      data = mpg) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, color = "black") +
      theme(legend.key.width = unit(4,"cm"))
plot2
```

I would like to be able to control the size of the symbols in the legend without affecting the thickness of the lines. Trying with the idea of using `override.aes` from similar threads gives bigger symbols but at the same time thicker lines.

```
plot2 + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

This question is partly described in  [Modifying legends in ggplot2 with interactions and guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169021/modifying-legends-in-ggplot2-with-interactions-and-guides); however, the question in the link adresses changes to `Geom_Path` and not `Geom_Smooth` and does not explain how to find the exact definition of the `ggproto()`-object to change. It would be helpful if someone could supply this information - then I could probably modify the code myself in a similar fashion.

Comment: Seems not to be possible... https://stackoverflow.com/q/51169021/1296582

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying legends in ggplot2 with interactions and guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169021/modifying-legends-in-ggplot2-with-interactions-and-guides)

Comment: Thanks for the link which i did not find myself. This might solve the problem. The problem here is with `geom_smooth` in stead of `geom_path` and I can probably modify the code the same way as explained for `geom_path` but I don't know where to find the definition for `geom_smooth` to modify...??